# Angular bootstrap dropdown toggle - navigate through keyboard arrow key

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am using bootstrap's dropdown toggle directive. But I could navigate the menus thru mouse but not thru the keyboard arrow key. 
Please let me know how to navigate thru keyboard up/down arrow keys.

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/m5TBlkVMVJHVF69V2635?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

For Bootstrap dropdowns, the up/down arrows rely on being able to "focus" the anchors, which requires the `href` attribute be specified.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{choice}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note use of `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of the usual `href="#"`, because the latter will cause AngularJS to reload the page due to the route changing.

Comment: Solution proposed by Peter Davis works. Should be the accepted answer.